# C# How to delete selected datagridview rows and also delete them in database?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a datagridview with multiselect set to true, my question is how can I delete multiple selected items in the datagridview and also delete them in the database when I press the delete button?

Comment: Retrieve the list of selected rows, for each selected row, remove the item in the database, then remove the selected rows from the grid. What aspect are having problems with?

Comment: I'm new to programming can you please show me how can I assign the list of selected rows into list or an array? And how to delete these multiple items in the mysql database?

Comment: A lot of this depends on how you are connecting to you data base. What have you tried?